# Does xamarin.android support DownloadHelper?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

The download is started by the user clicking on the Download File button. The Xamarin.Android application utilizes a ProgressBar widget to display the download progress.

The button that begins the download has the following asynchronous event handler assigned to it's Click event:

```
async void StartDownloadHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _progressBar.Progress = 0;
    Progress<DownloadBytesProgress> progressReporter = new Progress<DownloadBytesProgress>();
    progressReporter.ProgressChanged += (s, args) => _progressBar.Progress = (int)(100 * args.PercentComplete);

    Task<int> downloadTask = DownloadHelper.CreateDownloadTask(DownloadHelper.ImageToDownload, progressReporter);
    int bytesDownloaded = await downloadTask;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} bytes.", bytesDownloaded);
}
```

In the previous code snippet, the Progress encapsulates a lambda that will update ProgressBar, displaying the percentage of bytes that were downloaded. It is important to realize that Progress will execute in the same SynchronizationContext it which it was instantiated. So, because Progress is created on the UI thread, it will run in the UI thread. It is not necessary to explicitly use RunOnUIThread inside the provided lambda to update the UI.

I dont see DownloadHelper on xamarin.android. I want to create a download method